# Insert no duplicate name PHP

Tags: php, sql, function, insert, duplicates

I have this form and this function for insert name in db:

```
<form action="player.php#insertPlayer" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nameplayer" />
    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter joueur" />
</form>

function insertPlayer($name) {
    db connection
    if (empty ($name))
        {echo "<span style='color: red'>WRONG!!!!</span>";}
    else
    {
        $insertplayer="INSERT INTO `player`(id, name) VALUES ('','$name');";
        echo 'player insert succes';
        mysql_close($db);
    }

}
```

But if i enter 2 same name, it's work, how can i do for just have always one same name ?

Comment: You could set the name column to be unique in the database or query the database before inserting.

Comment: Ok, and in query how to do ?

Comment: select count(*) count from usertable where name = '$name' then add some logic, if count > 0 insert player

Comment: Keep the name column in player table as UNIQUE.Run this alter statement on your DB `ALTER TABLE player
ADD UNIQUE (name)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-a-field-unique

Answer (score 0):

To make `player` table column name as UNIQUE, run the below ALTER statement on your corresponding Database.

`ALTER TABLE player ADD UNIQUE (name)`;

If already the player table has some data with duplicate values in `name` column, the alter statement will fail. So clear the data from `player` table before running the ALTER statement.