# How do you make a field unique from within HeidiSQL

Tags: heidisql

I'm new to HeidiSQL and can't seem to find a manual. How can I make a field unique from inside the client? I see [this post here describing the SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-a-field-unique) that I need. Is there a way to do this in the client with a check mark or something? Is it also possible to call a SQL statement from within HeidiSQL that would accomplish my goal?

Comment: yes, this was extremely helpful. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the table you want to alter. There is a tab called "Indexes" there. Add a new index. Add the column you want to make unique to this index. Under "Type / Length", select UNIQUE. Then save.

Comment: I made my TINYTEXT field UNIQUE using your suggestion. But upon saving received SQL error 1170 about needing a key length. I tried changing my field to CHAR(100) and that seemed to work ok. Is UNIQUE not appropriate for TINYTEXT fields?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double click on your table
2. Select Indexes tab , under Type/Length select Unique
3. Drag the column to that index ,which you want to make unique
4. click on save