# How to insert into mysql with Boolean condition

Tags: mysql

I have this statement that I wanna execute:

```
INSERT INTO kitchenitems (kno, `date`, added_Date, added_By) 
VALUES (5,'2016-04-01', now(), 2);
```

but before it executes i wanna check whether "kno" has "5" or not. If not it should execute. If has it should not execute. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `kno` a primary key? or a wanna-be primary key?

Comment: @Sevle no its not the PK

Comment: if the number 5 is dynamic, it must be produced by programming language (not sql).  Can't you check the number in a if statement on that side?

Comment: Alternatively you could use a stored procedure if it has to be mysql that checks the "5".

Comment: that is how i do it now get it to a resultset and check. but i wanna increase the efficiency i saw somewhere that it can be done.  @JonathanClark i do not get it.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    INSERT INTO kitchenitems (`kno`, `date`, `added_Date`,`added_By`)
    SELECT kno,date,added_Date,added_By
    FROM (SELECT '5' as kno, '2016-04-01' as date, NOW() as added_Date, '2' as added_By) a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM kitchenitems b WHERE a.kno = b.kno);
```

**However**, if you want unique values of `kno`, you should [ensure that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-an-existing-field-unique) at server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can easealy be done with stored procedure... I would suggest you to read this article [HERE](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/05/06/mysql-stored-procedures-if-not-exists/) I think that's the answer on your solution.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/064f6/1) to see how that works on your problem...

here is your stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addItem 
(IN inkno INT, IN inddate DATETIME, IN inadded_Date DATETIME, IN inadded_By INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE SomeId int;
    DECLARE CheckExists int;  
    SET CheckExists = 0;  

    SELECT count(*) INTO CheckExists from kitchenitems WHERE kno = inkno;   

    IF (CheckExists > 0) THEN 
        SELECT kno INTO SomeId FROM kitchenitems WHERE kno = inkno;  
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO kitchenitems (kno,ddate,added_Date,added_By) 
        VALUES (inkno, inddate,inadded_Date, inadded_By); 
    END IF;

END/
```