# Make sure every entry in a table is unique

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with thousands of rows, and I think the algorithm that inserted those rows may have been glitched and inserted some duplicate data. Is there a quick, SQL-only way to ensure that every row is different, or do I have to manually select every row, load it into a PHP array, and check that all items are unique?

Note: I know how to do this (the long and hard way), but I'm asking if there's a shortcut or a better way.

Comment: Try to add a unique constraint on every column in the table. It will fail if there's duplicate data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-an-existing-field-unique

Comment: @Ghost I believe that OP was asking how to make it so that the field remains unique after future submissions. I'm asking how to look at past submissions.

Comment: what do you want to do when you find a duplicate? there are lots of previous questions on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+find+duplicates

Comment: Select count(*), column1, column2... ColumnN group by column1, column2... ColumnN </br> here column1, column2... ColumnN  are the name of all of your columns. If anything in count comes more than one, it has been inserted myltiple times

Comment: @Bluefire *"I'm asking how to look at past submissions"* <- that's not how your question sounds to me, specifically *"Is there a quick, SQL-only way to ensure that every row is different"*

Comment: @Phil ensure that every row in the table is different. So every row that the table contains right now is different.