# I want to delete duplicate rows from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I want to delete duplicate rows from this MySQL table without creating a temp table. I tried to do it "WITH CTE" but that doesn't work as I am using MySQL-Workbench.

[image: Please click here to view the table:]

I tried to achieve the result using this query but it's not working.

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE 
(SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT row_number() OVER (partition by id) rn FROM employee) 
 alias) > 1;
```

I want to delete all duplicate rows but keep one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: Alsi if you don't want to keep duplicate values, just [make the column UNIQUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-an-existing-field-unique)

Comment: @Prãshant Saraswat do you want to keep one of them?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep one of the duplicate records.